# Как одному компоненту Swing передать данные от нескольких компонентов?

Tags: java, swing

Во время малоуспешных попыток изучения swing придумал пример с двумя комбинированными списками и текстовым полем. По задумке, пользователь выбирает в каждом списке значения, а некий результат любых действий над ними должен выводиться в текстовое поле.

В итоге, не могу добиться ОДНОВРЕМЕННОГО получения обоих значений. А надо. Подскажите, в чем ошибка?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class MainFrame extends JFrame {
    public MainFrame() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        //Поле для вывода
        getContentPane().add(text = new JTextArea(1, 10));

        //заполняем списки
        comboMonth = new JComboBox();
        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
            comboMonth.addItem(i + 1);
        getContentPane().add(comboMonth);

        comboYear = new JComboBox();
        for (int i = 1900; i <= 2100; i++)
            comboYear.addItem(i);
        getContentPane().add(comboYear);

        //подключаем слушателей
        comboMonth.addActionListener(new comboMonthL());
        comboYear.addActionListener(new comboYearL());

        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private JTextArea text;
    private JComboBox comboMonth, comboYear;

    class comboMonthL implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JComboBox month = (JComboBox)e.getSource();
            int monthI = (int)month.getSelectedItem();
            text.setText(monthI + "");
        }
    }

    class comboYearL implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JComboBox year = (JComboBox)e.getSource();
            int yearI = (int)year.getSelectedItem();
            text.setText(yearI + "");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MainFrame();
    }
}
```

**Другой класс:**

```
public class Calendar1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                MainFrame CalFrame = new MainFrame();
                CalFrame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пробема кроется тут

```
 text.setText(monthI + "");
 text.setText(yearI + "");
```

Вы в разных лисенерах проставляете в одно поле разные значения. Вам либо надо запоминать текст который в поле, добавлять к нему новый текст и уже новый текст выводить.

Или можно так - в лисенере для года запонимаете значение (в переменную класса, например), в лисенере для месяца вы забираете сохраненую переменную, к ней дописываете месяц, и уже это проставляете в текстовое поле.

Будет примерно так

```
 public class MainFrame extends JFrame {
     private int currentYear;
     public MainFrame() {
             ....
     }
     class comboYearL implements ActionListener {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
             JComboBox year = (JComboBox) e.getSource();
             currentYear = (int) year.getSelectedItem();
         }
     }
     class comboMonthL implements ActionListener {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
             JComboBox month = (JComboBox) e.getSource();
             int monthI = (int) month.getSelectedItem();
             text.setText(currentYear + " " + monthI);
         }
     }
```

Если надо в обе стороны - то делаете подобную переменую для месяца и выполняете аналогичные действия

Comment: Спасибо! Это уже перегруз просто был. Сознание сузилось так, что область видимости переменных уже вышла из поля зрения.